# How to extend a child element when parent element has padding inside?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a parent div with padding and a child div inside the parent div:

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the child div align with the left edge of the parent, with padding present? Class `a` cannot be changed.

Comment: Negative margin of the same amount for all sides but bottom for `.b` … `margin: -10px -10px 0 -10px;`

Comment: @CBroe why all sides but bottom? Would `margin-left: -10px` be sufficient?

Comment: With just a margin on the left side, the element would not go over the whole width of the parent any more (which I assumed you probably wanted.) If you don’t want it to align with the top corner of the parent as well, then of course it does not need the negative margin-top.

Comment: I see. I did just want the element to just align with the left edge, not top edge. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did mention that class `a` cannot be changed.